# Node.js & MySQL - Error: 1251 - Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

Right now I have only this code:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = new Sequelize('database', 'root', 'passwd', {
  host: 'localhost',
  dialect: 'mysql',

    // http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html#operators
  operatorsAliases: false
});
sequelize
  .authenticate()
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', err);
  });
```

But when I try to run the .js I get [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFeDd.png). I have already tried a lot of solutions out there, including the one I found [more often but it didn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZHVi.png). So right now I don't know what to do. Can somebody help me?

Thank you

Comment: What auth modes do you have configured for your server?

Comment: caching_sha2_password

Answer (score 31):

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password'
```

Worked for me. root password is changed to 'password'

Comment: This worked for me too. I think this is due to the use of SHA256 for password storage in new version of mysql.

Comment: I was working on Docker containers and I needed to change in the query `localhost` to `%` because I was connecting to a different hostname. It works!

Comment: thanks for your answer, it worked for me and it saves lot of time. thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Changing the plugin to mysql_native_password might solve the problem!

```
use mysql;
update user set authentication_string=password(''), plugin='mysql_native_password' where user='root';
```

Comment: It was in fact about changing the plugin to mysql_native_password but not in that way because as I said on my previous post I tried that but the syntax was wrong. I searched on MySQL documentation and I found this:
     ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost'
      IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password
      BY 'password';

And this worked! Thanks for the help though :)

Comment: just to clarify, the syntax might be a little different, in my case, it was `... set authentication_string='password', ...`

Answer (score 1):

Basically when I was trying to connect to Mysql Query Browser at that time I as facing the issue.

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'root'
```

Worked for me. root password is changed to 'root'

Answer (score 1):

I found out that I was caused by incorrect parameters.

```
{ database: 'abc',
  username: undefined,
  password: 'efsefs',
}
```

username is undefined, but the error is "consider upgrading MySQL client"
So modify the user name to be true, the error resolved.

Comment: Thank you. This was the issue. The environment variable was named USER and wasn't being loaded into the process.env object. I changed its name to MYSQL_USER and it became available and the connection worked.