# Docker log- getting error- 'upgrading MySQL client'

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker, docker-compose

im getting the error on docker:

```
Error: ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE: Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client
code: 'ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE',
errno: 1251
sqlMessage: 'Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client',
sqlState: '08004'
```

Im trying to send data from client to server, from server to mysql db
and see it using phpAdmin.
It looks like that the datawas successfully sent to the server from the client,
but not sent from the server to the db.
There is no data in the table after send it.
I think the problem is something with the env but I dont get it...

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.9"

x-common-variables: &common-variables
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
  MYSQL_DATABASE: shimshon
  MYSQL_HOST_IP: localhost
  REACT_APP_SERVER_PORT: 3001

services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0
    restart: unless-stopped
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    environment:
      <<: *common-variables
      MYSQL_HOST: mysql
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    volumes:
      - ./db/sample.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/sample.sql
  phpmyadmin:
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    environment:
      <<: *common-variables
      PMA_HOST: mysql
    links:
      - mysql:mysql
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    restart: always
  server:
    build: ./server
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    expose:
      - 3001
    environment:
      <<: *common-variables
      MYSQL_HOST_IP: mysql
    ports:
      - 3001:3001
    volumes:
      - ./server:/app
    links:
      - mysql
    command: npm run devStart
  client:
    build: ./client
    environment:
      <<: *common-variables
      NODE_PATH: src
    expose:
      - 3000
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - ./client/src:/app/src
    links:
      - server
    command: npm start
```

server.js:

```
...
const db = mysql.createConnection({
  host: process.env.MYSQL_HOST_IP,
  user: process.env.MYSQL_USER,
  password: process.env.MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.MYSQL_DATABASE,
  port : 3306
});
...
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node.js & MySQL - Error: 1251 - Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49991865/node-js-mysql-error-1251-client-does-not-support-authentication-protocol)

Comment: I also don't see how this is about programming.  It's about upgrading an application.

Comment: I solved it, nedded to add .0 image: mysql:8.0.0